# Can' scroll on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, web, scroll

I've seen this question asked some times before but their solution didn't help me. I set e page up on the following domain: http://www.beuy.ch/. Unfortunately i can't scroll with mobile devices on this page. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I can scroll, but only until your canvas is loaded. Then seems like the scroll action from the device is only taken as a movement in the canvas. Problem is clearly related to your dynamic canvas...

Comment: Thanks for your answert! I see what you mean. But know it's totally free of the js and the canvas - why the error still appears? It seems to me to have a relation with the finally loaded page!?